# How to use linux command line for image load time on certain webpage?

Tags: linux, image, curl, page-load-time

Recently I have been focusing on the page loading time, and my concern is the time of loading certain **image** on a webpage. What confuses me is how to use the **linux command line** to do this. Is **cURL** helpful? If so, how can I do?  Or are there any other ways?

Any advice and solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new File on Desktop or whereever you want.. like curl-format.txt

Paste this in this file:

```
    time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}\n
       time_connect:  %{time_connect}\n
    time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\n
   time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\n
      time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\n
 time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
         time_total:  %{time_total}\n
```

make a request:

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o <path/to/the/file> -s "webpagelink.com"
```

Comment: idk what you want.. just the time for the image or for the complete webpage ?

Comment: Yep, I just want the time for the image. Besides, if I just put one image on an website and then use `curl` to get the load time of this website, it may not be the exact image load time. So whether `curl` can do this? If so, how?  @xEmrah